# How to assign values from column 1 to column 2 when column 1 is > 0 and column 2 is <= 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df`,

```
delta1    delta2
  0         -1
  2          0
 -1          0
  0          0
```

I am wondering how to assign values of `delta2` to `delta1` only if `delta1 > 0` and `delta2 <= 0`; the result look like,

```
delta1    delta2
  0         -1
  0          0
 -1          0
  0          0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['delta1'] = np.where(df.delta1.gt(0) & df.delta2.le(0), df.delta2, df.delta1)
```

```
   delta1  delta2
0       0      -1
1       0       0
2      -1       0
3       0       0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below:

```
m=df.delta1.gt(0)&df.delta2.le(0)
df.loc[m,'delta1']=df.delta2
print(df)
   delta1  delta2
0       0      -1
1       0       0
2      -1       0
3       0       0
```

Comment: Instead of assigning `0`, you should assign `delta2`.  He says "I am wondering how to assign values of delta2 to delta1"